# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, wordpress, smarty

I am using smarty templates for pinnaclecart to pull post data from wordpress database so the website can show the blog posts. I fixed IF unexpected error but now it is back to $this. I m stuck :(

public_blog.php

**EDIT back**

```
    function getPosts()
{
        $query= $this->db->query("
        SELECT * from wp_posts where post_status='publish' AND post_type = 'post'
        ");

        $posts = array();
        if ($this->db->moveNext($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
                 $posts[] = $this->db->col;

        }
return $posts;

}
$posts = getPosts();
view()->assign("body", "templates/pages/site/blog.html");
```

Could not figure IF error part

The help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error in your title leads me to believe that you aren't using a class at all. `$this` can only be used in functions that are in a class.

See related:
[Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fatal%20error:%20Using%20$this%20when%20not%20in%20object%20context)

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = array();
```

Missing semi colon